# Filter features by property which is a list of objects in Mapbox

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I am working on filtering in my mapbox-gl-js map. I have a Feature which looks similar to this:

```
[
    {
        "latitude": 1.0,
        "longitude": 1.0,
        "name": null,
        "description": null,
        "id": 3,
        "mappings": [
            {
                "type": "A",
                "mode": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3"
                ]
            },
            {
                "type": "B",
                "mode": [
                    "2",
                    "1",
                    "5"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Now, I would like to create a filter, which shows only a features, which have type = A AND mode = 1. Is such a complex filtering possible? I am struggling with expressions like this:

```
this.map.setFilter('points2', ['==', ['get', 'type', ['object', ['get', 'mappings']]], 'A']));
```

but it seems to make no sense.

I also tried to manipulate data from backend and created following geoJson:

```
[
    {
        "latitude": 1.0,
        "longitude": 1.0,
        "name": null,
        "description": null,
        "id": 3,
        "mappings": {
            "A": [
                "1",
                "2",
                "3"
            ],
            "B": [
                "3",
                "2",
                "1"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

It looks a bit easier than previous json, but I am not able to write a proper filters, because documentation doesn't even tell a word about such cases as far as I saw. I also added a Leafletjs tag to this question, because maybe there is a nice solution in leaflet library for this.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of Mapbox creators answered my question: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/8963.